# Log4J-1.12.x.jar - how to address the vulnerablity

Tags: security, log4j

Currently we have 200+ java-based application that are using the log4j-1.12.x version. Upgrading this in one shot will be next to impossible. Is there any other remediation available/suggested for this?

Comment: make sure that your 200 apps have no network connection to or from the internet.

Comment: There is not version 1.12.x. Did you mean 2.12.x or 1.2.x? If it is the latter, Log4j 1.2 is not affected by Log4j 2.x vulnerability.